# Adding dynamic generic html control to page destroys bound dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I encountered some weird behaviour today and I was hoping someone could shed some light on it for me because I'm perplexed.

I have a couple of methods I use to interact with the ui for the sole purpose of displaying error/success/warning messages to the user.

Here is one of them

```
        public static void Confirm(string text)
    {
        var page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        var uiConfirm = new HtmlGenericControl("div")
        {
            ID = "uiNotify",
            InnerHtml = text
        };
        uiConfirm.Attributes.Add("class", "ui-confirm");
        page.Master.FindControl("form1").Controls.AddAt(2, uiConfirm);
    }
```

This works perfectly fine except for one nuance I encountered this morning and I was hoping someone could shed some light on it for me.

I am working on your run of the mill profile editing page. In this page, I am binding a couple of dropdownlists (country, province/state) on page load. I have a submit at the bottom and a click event that fires to update the information, then call the method above to notify the user that their information was successfully updated. This works the first time you click the submit button; the page posts back, the information gets updated in the database, the dynamically added div gets popped in, confirm message is displayed and all is good. However, if you then click the submit button again, it fails stating SelectedItem on the dropdowns I'm binding in the page load is null (Object reference not set to an instance of an object). The dropdown is actually wiped for some reason on the *second* postback, but not the first.

In sheer desperation after trying everything else, I decided to take out the call to the confirm method... and strangely enough the error disappears and I can update the information on the page as many times as I like.

If I add a generic control statically to the page I'm working on, and change my method slightly so that instead of adding a generic control to the form dynamically it just finds the generic control on the page, that does no produce the same error.

The problem also goes away if I remove the two dropdowns from the page or just stop interacting with them.

Why on earth would adding a dynamic control to the form wipe my dropdowns on postback?

Comment: what does your `Page_Load` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider using the [`PlaceHolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx) class in your `MasterPage`, the `AddAt(2, uiConfirm)` is going to bite you and probably is:

**Markup:**

```
.......
<asp:PlaceHolder id="PlaceHolder1" 
           runat="server"/>
......
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public static void Confirm(string text)
{
    var page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    var uiConfirm = new HtmlGenericControl("div")
    {
        ID = "uiNotify",
        InnerHtml = text
    };
    uiConfirm.Attributes.Add("class", "ui-confirm");

    //may need to change depending on where you put your placeholder
    Control placeHolder = page.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolder1"); 
    placeHolder.Controls.Clear();
    placeHolder.Controls.Add(uiConfirm);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing with my workaround at the moment. I am more curious as to the reason why the original code would be a problem. You say to steer clear of AddAt because it will end up biting me, any specific reason for that?

Comment: Yes, you are referencing the control collection by index and assuming it's not going to change.  My suggestion is to find a known placeholder and inject within it so control order does not matter.